# Spring security Google signin, controller doesn't redirect to my index.html

Tags: spring-security, google-signin

My application has a login page which uses spring security. Then I would like to add "Sign in with Google" button likes following:

[add google signin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULpj7.png)

Then if user click signin with google, it should send a post request, following is my javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/tokensigningoogle');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
                'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
    }
  </script>
```

Then I added a MVC controller to get the GrantedAuthorities since I need to get the roles of the current user. Then I want to redirect to my index.html. It doesn't have errors when I run it in eclipse, however, it can not redirect to my index.html and it still stayes in my login.jsp.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/tokensigningoogle")
public class SigninWithGoogle {
    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SigninWithGoogle.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String processRegistration(@RequestParam("idtoken") String idTokenString, ModelMap model)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory())
                .setAudience(Arrays.asList(Config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)).setIssuer("accounts.google.com").build();

        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
        if (idToken != null) {
            Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
            // Print user identifier
            String userId = payload.getSubject();
            // Get profile information from payload
            String email = payload.getEmail();
            boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
            List<User> users = DbFunction.listHqlNew("FROM User WHERE email = :email", "email", email);

            if (!emailVerified || users.isEmpty()) {
                return "/error.html";
            } else {
                List<String> roles = DbFunction.listSQLNew(
                        "SELECT role.name FROM user_role_association JOIN role ON role.id = role_id JOIN user on user.id = user_id WHERE user.email = :email",
                        "email", email);

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for (String role : roles) {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                }

                UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(users.get(0).getName(),
                        "xx", users.get(0).isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(users.get(0).getName(), null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                return "/index.html";
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        }
        return "/error.html";
    }
}
```